# Create a graph (plot) on the data of the nested dictionary in matplotlib

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib

I can build a simple plot in a matplotlib according to the 'simple' dictionary:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
D = {u'Label1':26, u'Label2': 17, u'Label3':30}
plt.bar(range(len(D)), D.values(), align='center')
plt.xticks(range(len(D)), D.keys())
```

[image]

But, how do I create two graphics on the data of these dictionaries on one the plot I do not know?

```
NG1={'need1': [{'good1': 3, 'good2': 4}], 'need2': [{'good2': 2, 'good3': 2}]}
NG2={'need1': [{'good1': 13, 'good2': 23}], 'need2': [{'good2': 8, 'good3': 14}]}
```

Like the picture below

[image]

Comment: What is the desired result? What do you expect the graph to look like?

Comment: Hi! Tell me, this is possible to create or not, using matplotlib?

Answer (score 5):

using `pandas` you can do approximately what I think you want

```
NG1={'need1': {'good1': 3, 'good2': 4}, 'need2': {'good2': 2, 'good3': 2}}
NG2={'need1': {'good1': 13, 'good2': 23}, 'need2': {'good2': 8, 'good3': 14}}
```

(notice the lack of `[]`)

```
combined_df = pd.concat({'ng1': pd.DataFrame(NG1), 'ng2': pd.DataFrame(NG2)}).unstack(0)
```

> ```
> combined_df
> ```

```
   need1            need2
    ng1     ng2     ng1     ng2
good1   3.0     13.0    NaN     NaN
good2   4.0     23.0    2.0     8.0
good3   NaN     NaN     2.0     14.0
```

Depending on what exactly it is you want you can omit the `unstack`

```
combined_df.plot.bar()
```

delivers

[image: bar plot]

## edit update

I cannot create exactly what you need in this way, You would need to play around with different glyphs and figures and I don't have the skills or time to do this, but I can provide the data in the correct way

```
combined_df = pd.concat({'ng1': pd.DataFrame(NG1), 'ng2': pd.DataFrame(NG2)}).stack()
combined_df.index.names = ['ng', 'good', 'need']
combined_df = combined_df.unstack(['good'])
combined_df['sum'] = combined_df.sum(axis=1)
```

> ```
> combined_df
> ```

```
    good    good1   good2   good3   sum
ng  need                
ng1     need1   3.0     4.0     NaN     7.0
need2   NaN     2.0     2.0     4.0
ng2     need1   13.0    23.0    NaN     36.0
need2   NaN     8.0     14.0    22.0
```

> ```
> combined_df.plot.bar()
> ```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I add the question with the figure below. Tell me this is possible to create or not?

Comment: And how to make two drawings : ng1 (need1, need2) and ng2 (need1, need2) on the one picture. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Adding to [@MaartenFabré 's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46791889/4124317), you can get the sum as another bar plot in the background by plotting the sum as an individual bar plot and make it unfilled,

```
combined_df['sum'].plot.bar(zorder=0, fill=False)
```

Complete solution:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

NG1={'need1': {'good1': 3, 'good2': 4}, 'need2': {'good2': 2, 'good3': 2}}
NG2={'need1': {'good1': 13, 'good2': 23}, 'need2': {'good2': 8, 'good3': 14}}

combined_df = pd.concat({'ng1': pd.DataFrame(NG1), 'ng2': pd.DataFrame(NG2)}).stack()
combined_df.index.names = ['ng', 'good', 'need']
combined_df = combined_df.unstack(['good'])

combined_df.plot.bar()

combined_df['sum'] = combined_df.sum(axis=1)
combined_df['sum'].plot.bar(zorder=0, fill=False)


plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: And how to make two drawings : ng1 (need1, need2) and ng2 (need1, need2) on the one picture. Is this possible?